# Best web UI within .NET stack?

Tags: .net, user-interface, blazor

I'm trying to decide on which UI technology to use in terms of Visual Studio 2022 template integration and staying in the .NET stack converting an older legacy UI from .NET 4.6 ASP/JS.

Web API will be .NET 6 Core/EF.

Project templates in VS 2022:

- ASP.NET Core with React.js
- ASP.NET Core with Angular
- Blazor WebAssembly hosted by ASP.NET
- Blazor Server App hosted by ASP.NET
- ASP.NET Core Web App Razor

I have experience with Angular but it's a different development process in terms of debugging and access to .NET core web API.  It would be nice to have a single "debug" experience for both UI and web API.

Server will be IIS 10

I was going to evaluate MAUI but we're staying web app only and don't need mobile apps ... not to mention MAUI seems to require a special Beta version of VS 2022.

I'm leaning towards Blazor since it seems to be tailored to the .NET stack.

Thoughts?

Comment: The natural choice for Asp.Net developers is to stick to .Net; in other words, to use Blazor. If your app is a corporate web site, I would recommand using `Blazor Server App.` If its public, use  Blazor WebAssembly hosted or Blazor WebAssembly standalone, depending on a couple of factors. In any case, do create a Web Api project for your end points; Do not integrate the Web Api controllers within the Server-side project of the `Blazor WebAssembly hosted App.` I also have some experience with Angular, but have made a decision to migrate to Blazor (about 4 years ago).

Comment: I know nothing about your project, so it is not easy to add further ideas, etc.', except that no matter how well you are with Asp.Net Core (Razor Pages or MVC), you need to learn Blazor (especially the Component Model, all the aspects of security (authentication, authorization, and so on)). If you are a WebForms developer with no further knowledge, say, of  Razor Pages or MVC, you'll have to work hard... very hard, indeed. Another thing that I have to mention is that you should always create your components in component libraries....

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Yes, I'm sure it will get closed even though UI technology advances daily (ok maybe monthly) so if this is a repeat and problem for admins, it's relevant for this "point in time".